# NPE when setting the visibility of a nested LinearLayout in a custom AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, visibility, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to show a custom AlertDialog. I have a LinearLayout within the main LinearLayout  that contains a few buttons. The buttons are only supposed to show at certain times, so I'm trying to set the layout to GONE. However, this throws a NPE at the line indicated below. Any ideas?

```
 @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {      
        //case 0 removed for purposes of space
        case 1: 
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ingamepopup,null);

        if(getPrefs.getBoolean("custom button checked"+gameNum, false)){
            customButtonLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            cb1.setText(Float.toString(getPrefs.getFloat("button 1 value"+gameNum,1)));
            cb2.setText(Float.toString(getPrefs.getFloat("button 2 value"+gameNum,5)));
            cb3.setText(Float.toString(getPrefs.getFloat("button 3 value"+gameNum,10)));
        } else
            customButtonLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); //Line 172

        scoreChangeDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Score change")
        .setView(view)
        .create();

        return scoreChangeDialog;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

customButtonLayout is defined in onCreate():

```
customButtonLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llCustomButtonsScoreChange);
```

And defined in R:

```
public static final int llCustomButtonsScoreChange=0x7f070015;
```

And the LogCat:

```
      08-14 13:56:07.192: E/AndroidRuntime(10020): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 13:56:07.192: E/AndroidRuntime(10020): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 13:56:07.192: E/AndroidRuntime(10020):    at com.webs.pratia.scorekeeper.InGame.onCreateDialog(InGame.java:172)
08-14 13:56:07.192: E/AndroidRuntime(10020):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateDialog(Activity.java:2472)
08-14 13:56:07.192: E/AndroidRuntime(10020):    at android.app.Activity.createDialog(Activity.java:881)
08-14 13:56:07.192: E/AndroidRuntime(10020):    at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2547)
08-14 13:56:07.192: E/AndroidRuntime(10020):    at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2514)
08-14 13:56:07.192: E/AndroidRuntime(10020):    at com.webs.pratia.scorekeeper.InGame.onListItemClick(InGame.java:121)
08-14 13:56:07.192: E/AndroidRuntime(10020):    at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:321)
08-14 13:56:07.192: E/AndroidRuntime(10020):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:289)
08-14 13:56:07.192: E/AndroidRuntime(10020):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3688)
08-14 13:56:07.192: E/AndroidRuntime(10020):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1873)
08-14 13:56:07.192: E/AndroidRuntime(10020):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-14 13:56:07.192: E/AndroidRuntime(10020):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-14 13:56:07.192: E/AndroidRuntime(10020):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-14 13:56:07.192: E/AndroidRuntime(10020):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-14 13:56:07.192: E/AndroidRuntime(10020):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 13:56:07.192: E/AndroidRuntime(10020):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-14 13:56:07.192: E/AndroidRuntime(10020):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-14 13:56:07.192: E/AndroidRuntime(10020):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
08-14 13:56:07.192: E/AndroidRuntime(10020):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Edit**

After some more testing, it seems that all of my variables defined in ingamepopup.xml return null (like cb1, cb2, cb3). ingamepopup.xml is not the main xml for the activity. Is there some conflict between setContentView(ingame.xml) and trying to access view from ingamepopup.xml (which is inflated by the inflater)?

Comment: +1 nice style to ask a question!!! and check your layout xml file which you set as contentview and also check id of customButtonLayout.

Comment: Is this called before `setContentView`? Because `llCustomButtons` may be an ID, but it is returning a `null` object when referenced.

Comment: My question was previously misleading. The LL I'm trying to set to invisible is not in the xml that the contentview is set to, but it is in an XML for an AlertDialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem. Since I was trying to reference objects (correct terminology?) from the view in the AlertDialog, I had reference the view I inflated: view.findViewById(...). By stating findViewById(...) the program was trying to find the ID from the view loaded to the main activity. The new code looks like:

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ingamepopup,null); //This is the view that has to be referenced.

            mainLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llScoreChange); 
//notice view.findViewById(...)
            customButtonLayout = (LinearLayout)  view.findViewById(R.id.llCustomButtonsScoreChange);
            plus = (ImageButton)  view.findViewById(R.id.ibPlusPU);
            minus = (ImageButton)  view.findViewById(R.id.ibMinusPU);
            cancel = (ImageButton)  view.findViewById(R.id.ibCancelPU);
            cb1 = (Button)  view.findViewById(R.id.bCustom1PU);
            cb2 = (Button)  view.findViewById(R.id.bCustom2PU);
            cb3 = (Button)  view.findViewById(R.id.bCustom3PU);
            score = (EditText)  view.findViewById(R.id.etScoreChange);

            if(getPrefs.getBoolean("custom button checked"+gameNum, false)){
                customButtonLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                cb1.setText(Float.toString(getPrefs.getFloat("button 1 value"+gameNum,1)));
                cb2.setText(Float.toString(getPrefs.getFloat("button 2 value"+gameNum,5)));
                cb3.setText(Float.toString(getPrefs.getFloat("button 3 value"+gameNum,10)));
            } else{
                customButtonLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            scoreChangeDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Score change")
            .setView(view)
            .create();

            return scoreChangeDialog;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A NPE in this line means customButtonLayout is null.As View is a class and thus can't be null. Looks like you're aware of this. Now if customButtonLayout is null there might be different reasons for this

1. Create has not yet been called. As you try to hide the view I assume it's been showed before. If so it's not an option.
2. findViewById didn't find a view. Same logic applies.
3. Last option is someone set it to null after it's been initialized. This one is very obvious and you likely already analyzed it.
4. This call is done on one instance while another one has been initialized. Maybe customButtonLayout is defined in a super class and you assume it to be the same variable on every instance of subtypes. This is only true if it's a static member.

Comment: #2 essentially was the problem. findViewId did find a view, it just found the _wrong_ view.